# Rationale for lack of [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uikit

Apple has made clear that we should be migrating from methods that use NSString filepaths to ones that use NSURL. (Cannot find official documentation for this, hoping you can bear with me.)

One notable exception is `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)]` which does not have a corresponding `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:(NSString *)]`.

There is of course a workaround:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)]]
```

And of course this is "ugly". (Hoping again you can bear with me.)

Is there a specific documented or intuitive reason for this omission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLs can take a long time to respond.  They should not be fetched on the main thread as this makes the UI unresponsive.  So I think that is why `imageWithContentsOfURL` is not available.

I suggest having a placeholder image used for start-up and obtaining the contents of the URL in a background thread, and using a notification when the data is available for updating the `UIImage`.